# Multiplicación cero por cero en python

Tags: python, matemáticas, lambda

Tengo una multiplicación de funciones:

```
Gamma(x)= lambda x: densidad(x)*densidad(x+2.0*h+2.0*H)
```

dónde `h` y `H` son unas constantes que pueden tener cualquier valor (positivo o negativo) y la densidad está definida como:

```
def densidad(x):
  d = sqrt((((A-D)**2)/4.0)-(abs(x)-((A+D)/2.0))**2) # Elliptical
  return d
```

Mi problema está en que al imprimir `densidad(x)` o `densidad(x+2.0*h+2.0*H)` por separado la solución es correcta, pero al imprimir la multiplicación de ellas cuando las dos son cero, el resultado es un número negativo. Si una es cero y la otra no, da cero... No tengo ni idea porque sucede esto.

¿Tengo que definir algo más o es algún problema de flotantes?

Comment: ¿Cual es el valor de A y D?

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo reproducible? Sin conocer más es difícil saber donde falla.

Comment: Problema solucionado, la libreria Scipy convierte raices negativas en números complejos, al imprimir solo consideraba el número real que es cero, pero la multiplicación si la estaba realizando con los complejos y pues  i*i= -1, de ahí el real negativo.

Comment: @MelisaDomínguezGómez Deberías añadir ese comentario como respuesta o cerrar la pregunta.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque el OP solucionó el problema sin aportar detalles que permitan formular una respuesta.